# How change the content of last index in array?

Tags: javascript

I have one address and want to change some element,My address in bellow :

```
var address = "http://20.0.1.8/x-manufacturer/senders/d7aa5a30-681d-4e72-92fb-f0ba0f6f4c3e/sample-data";
```

I want to change the content of last index of var address "sample=data" to "new-data",I wrote the bellow code for solve it but didn't give me what I need!

```
let array_address = address.split('/');
var new address = array_address.splice(0,9,"new-data");//It just remove last index,didn't replace.
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is ment for arrays, not strings!

Comment: Strings don't have a `splice` function, only arrays. Also, even if `address` were an array, the code you gave would remove 9 elements from the start and insert "new-data" in. Also, `var new address` is incorrect syntax. Your code wouldn't do anything the way you presented it.

Comment: `address.replace("sample-data", "new-data")
`

Comment: before it I did this : address.split('/')

Comment: `splite` isn't a method either, its `split()` (no `e`). You should be able to see these errors in your browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you do not know what the last bit of the address is

```js
let url = new URL("http://20.0.1.8/x-manufacturer/senders/d7aa5a30-681d-4e72-92fb-f0ba0f6f4c3e/sample-data")
let path = url.pathname.split("/")
path[path.length-1] = "new-data"
url.pathname=path.join("/")
console.log(url.href)
```